# Git checkout with dot

Tags: git

What is the difference between the following `git` commands:

```
git  checkout branch
git  checkout branch .
git  checkout  .  #<-- used at the branch
```

Why when I checkout different branches into different folders with first one I missed some files.
But when I am using the second command, everything is ok?

Comment: That's not used "at the branch". The first argument is only considered to be a branch if it actually names one, which `.` doesn't. So it's simply path. It would only be branch if you said `git checkout . --`, upon which git would complain that there is no revision named `.`.

Comment: With the first form, you check out the branch into the current working copy. So what do you mean by "into different folders"?

Comment: I mean that i have for example 2 branches. And first will be checkoutted succesfully but the second miss some files. But if i use second line everything will be ok

Answer (score 79, accepted):

[`git checkout`(1)](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout.html) does very different things whether given path specifier or not.

1. With **branch specifier only** (`git checkout branch`) it will switch current working directory to specified branch, *keeping local changes if possible and failing otherwise*. If you already are on `branch`, it will do nothing at all. It only modifies files in the working directory that differ between `HEAD` and `branch` and fails if any of them has local modifications (indexed or not).
2. With **path specifier** it will overwrite the all matching files (all files match `.`) with specified content:

   1. With **path specifier only** (`git checkout .`) it writes content from index. That is, it undoes unstaged local modification. To undo staged modifications, use `git reset` with path specifier.
   2. With **both branch and path specifiers** (`git checkout branch .`) it writes content in specified revision. It will *not* modify where `HEAD` points, so if `branch` is different from `HEAD`, there will be unstaged changes afterwards.

Note, that the [man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout.html) distinguishes additional cases for use of the -b/--branch option and -p/--patch option, but those are mostly straightforward extensions of the above cases.

Comment: @Pepelac: It's right there in the man page; google finds several versions of that in the first page of results. Have you tried either?

Answer (score 21):

The above explanation is fine but let me explain with examples.

`git checkout` can be used with files folders and branches.

Let say there is `index.html` file and `dev` folder.

If I accidentally change `index.html` and i want to undo that I will simply run `git checkout index.html`. It will get my file back to its original form.

Now let say I made some changes inside dev folder and and want those changes back inside dev folder. If I will use `git checkout dev` and if there is any `dev` branch then it will checkout that **dev branch** rather than folder named `dev`.

So rather I would run 
`git checkout -- dev`

Now this bare double dash stands for current branch. So above command is asking from git is that please give me 'dev' named folder from current branch.

Lets talk about your use case.

`git  checkout branch` this command will simply checkout the branch named 'branch'

`git  checkout branch .` The second command will tell git that please checkout `.` or current folder name from the branch named 'branch'

`git  checkout  .  #<-- used at the branch` as you are saying first you switched to branch named 'branch' using `git checkout branch` then you are simply doing `git checkout .` Now there is no branch named `.` so it will simply pull down current folder name from current branch.

Comment: "Now this bare double dash stands for current branch. So above command is asking from git is that please give me 'dev' named folder from current branch." I dont think this statement is correct, the -- simply means, its the end of the options and the text that follows is the file path. And without a branch specified it means, take the changes in the index and not from the "current branch" as u mentioned(there is a difference between "index" and "current branch")