# git checkout <commit> . is not removing files that were added after the commit

Tags: git, git-checkout

Using a public repo, I want to get my master branch back to a certain commit from the past. I have reviewed the options and the best thing for me looks to be a simple checkout to the desired commit, then commit to the master branch. However when I do the checkout it does not remove some files that have been added into master after the specified commit hash.

So for example, if I want to get back to commit `aaa1`:

```
$ cd working-copy-top-dir
$ git checkout master
$ git checkout -- .
$ git clean -fd
$ git checkout aaa1 .
$ git clean -fd
```

But at this point some files added after `aaa1` are still in the working copy. What is the `checkout` command to get the working copy *data* back how it was at `aaa1`?

```
$ git --version
git version 2.7.2.windows.1
```

Comment: it may be due to the type of checkout i did http://stackoverflow.com/a/14460890/339874

Comment: I think you need to try [git reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-git-repo-to-a-previous-commit?lq=1

Answer (score 14):

#### TL;DR: remove everything first

When you used `git checkout aaa1 .`, you told Git to translate `aaa1` to a commit, find that commit (more precisely, its tree), and copy every file in that commit to your index / staging area and work-tree.

Let's say, just for the sake of argument, that you start with `master` containing two files, `README` and `hello`:

```
$ git checkout master
[output snipped]
$ ls
README   hello
$ cat README
Yay, you read me!
$ cat hello
world
$
```

Let's say further that commit `aaa1` exists and has two files in it, `README` and `addendum`.  Its `README` says `Thank you for reading.`  Let's do that checkout:

```
$ git checkout aaa1 -- .
[output snipped]
$ ls
README    addendum  hello
```

(I added the `--`: it's not actually required here, but it's good practice.)  The contents of `README` are the updated `README`.  The file `addendum` has also been extracted.  The file `hello` is *not* removed and remains unchanged from the version found in `master`.  The updated `README` and `hello` are staged:

```
$ git status --short
M  README
A  addendum
```

but `hello` is not removed:

```
$ git ls-files --stage
100644 ac6f2cf1acbe1b6f11c7be2288fbae72b982823c 0   README
100644 7ddf1d71e0209a8512fe4862b4689d6ff542bf99 0   addendum
100644 cc628ccd10742baea8241c5924df992b5c019f71 0   hello
```

Using `git clean`, even with `-x`, will have no effect: nothing needs cleaning; there are no unstaged files (`hello` is staged, it's just not *modified*).

---

You specifically wanted to get the work-tree to match commit `aaa1`, byte for byte.  To do that, you must find files that are in the index now, but were not in `aaa1`, and remove them.

There is, however, an easier way: just remove *everything*.  Then, use your `git checkout aaa1 -- .` to extract everything from `aaa1`.  This will fill in the index and work-tree from `aaa1`: any files that need to be restored to the way they were before removing, are restored (to the way they were in `aaa1` which is *the same* as the way they are in `HEAD`).  Any files that need to be changed to match the way they were in `aaa1`, are restored (to the way they were in `aaa1` which is *different*).

```
$ git rm -rf .
rm 'README'
rm 'addendum'
rm 'hello'
$ git checkout aaa1 -- .
$ git ls-files --stage
100644 ac6f2cf1acbe1b6f11c7be2288fbae72b982823c 0   README
100644 7ddf1d71e0209a8512fe4862b4689d6ff542bf99 0   addendum
$ git status --short
M  README
A  addendum
D  hello
```

You can now commit and you will have a new commit on `master` that, regardless of what was there before, has exactly the same tree as `aaa1`.

(Whether this is a *good idea* is another thing entirely, but it will get you the desired state.)

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to roll back your repo to that state? Or you just want your local repo to look like that?

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset for git reset.

**CASE 1:**
if you do

```
git reset --hard [commit hash]
```

It will make your local code and local history be just like it was at that commit. But then if you wanted to push this to someone else who has the new history, it would fail.

**CASE 2:** if you do

```
git reset --soft [commit hash]
```

It will make your local files changed to be like they were then, but leave your history etc. the same.

I found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3639154/2949612).
Also you can see related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489173/how-to-clone-git-repository-with-specific-revision-changeset).

Comment: its a public repo, so `git reset --soft` is what i need :)

Comment: hmm `git reset --soft aaa1` doesnt delete the files added after `aaa1` either. if i look in my working copy they are still there

Comment: YES, Glad to know it helps you.

Comment: Sorry, this is incorrect. `git reset --soft <commit-hash>` does *not* change the local files, as is mentioned in the man page: `--soft Does not the the index file or the working tree at all, but reset the head to <commit>`

Answer (score 1):

Git checkout [will not remove files added since a previous commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23205179/339874). To do this I would need `git revert`.

However I find `git checkout thehash .` a lot easier to use, and its not so hard to see which files have been added since that hash:

```
git diff --name-status HEAD thehash
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that this command updates both the index and the working copy to the commit that I want, given by variable `treeish` in this case:

```
# use with care: destroys any uncommitted changes
git read-tree "$treeish" --reset -u
```

To update the working copy without updating the index, you could perhaps do something like this:

```
index_bak=$(git write-tree)
git read-tree "$treeish" --reset -u
git read-tree "$index_bak" --reset
```

Answer (score 0):

**`git checkout --no-overlay` (git 2.22.0, June 2019)**

With this this option running:

```
git checkout --no-overlay <commit> <directory>
```

removes all files that were added under `<directory>` after `<commit>`. I wish that were the default behavior, but c'est la vie.

The option was [added by Thomas Gummerer at 091e04bc8cbb0c89c8112c4784f02a44decc257e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/091e04bc8cbb0c89c8112c4784f02a44decc257e) which went into git `v2.22.0`.

Test:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu

rm -rf tmp
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
git init

mkdir a
touch a/a
git add .
git commit -m a

mkdir b
touch b/b
git add .
git commit -m b

git checkout HEAD~ .
echo 'overlay'
ls -l . a b

git checkout --no-overlay HEAD~ .
echo 'no overlay'
ls -l . a b
```

Outcome:

```
git checkout HEAD~ .
echo 'overlay'
ls -l . a b
echo

git checkout --no-overlay HEAD~ .
echo 'no overlay'
ls -l . a b
echo
```

Output:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/ciro/test/git/tmp/.git/
[master (root-commit) 216d22e] a
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a/a
[master a36e67b] b
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 b/b
overlay
.:
total 2
drwxrwxr-x 2 ciro ciro 3 Jan 17 08:40 a
drwxrwxr-x 2 ciro ciro 3 Jan 17 08:40 b

a:
total 1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ciro ciro 0 Jan 17 08:40 a

b:
total 1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ciro ciro 0 Jan 17 08:40 b

no overlay
ls: cannot access 'b': No such file or directory
.:
total 1
drwxrwxr-x 2 ciro ciro 3 Jan 17 08:40 a

a:
total 1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ciro ciro 0 Jan 17 08:40 a
```

So we see that `b/b` only gets removed with `--no-overlay`. The directory `b` then also gets removed as usual in git commands because it would have become empty as a result of the git command.

Tested on Ubuntu 22.10, Git 2.37.2.

Answer (score -1):

*git stash* may be the quickest way to clean up the working tree.
and then *git checkout -b $newbranch $commit-sha1-you-want* to create a branch you are going to work with.
after all your work's done, *git stash pop* to restore the working tree.